# Apache POI not working in a modularised Java project caused by java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, illegalaccessexception

I have been having issues getting Apache POI to work in a JavaFX application, I am developing. I am using Maven to import the Apache poi and poi-ooxml jars. I've made a near-empty application that still produces the error so its easy to follow.

pom.xml file

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ssd</groupId>
    <artifactId>ssd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>16</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have also included the packages in my module-info file:

```java
module ssd {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.apache.poi.poi;
    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;
    requires java.desktop;

    opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}
```

Finally, in the main java file, I try to open an xlsx file using the Workbook class

```java
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            openFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void openFile() {
        FileInputStream fis;

        File file = new File("C:/Users/ogosi/Documents/sampleFile.xlsx");
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            Workbook w = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            Sheet s = w.getSheetAt(0);
            for (Row r : s) {
                System.out.println(r.getCell(0));
            }
        } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When this is run with a valid xlsx file get this error:

```java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile (in module org.apache.poi.ooxml) cannot access class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile (in unnamed module @0x624d6be6) because module org.apache.poi.ooxml does not read unnamed module @0x624d6be6
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1088)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:182)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:814)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:735)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:660)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:312)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.poi/org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.poi.poi/org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:295)
    at org.apache.poi.poi/org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.poi.poi/org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:163)
    at ssd/application.Main.openFile(Main.java:43)
    at ssd/application.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:179)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

What is interesting to note is that this error does not occur when I debug the program and use the resume button in Eclipse.

Solution:

"requires org.apache.commons.compress" was missing from the module-info file.

Comment: Take time to read some article about apache POI in reading xls/xlsx file. check this link https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html

Comment: Given this error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile (in module org.apache.poi.ooxml) cannot access class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile (in unnamed module @0x624d6be6) because module org.apache.poi.ooxml does not read unnamed module @0x624d6be6
aren't you missing a "requires org.apache.commons.compress" (or something like that)?

Comment: @moilejter That is indeed the issue thanks. All the examples I saw omitted this inclusion and it was made all the stranger when I could get it to work in debug mode.